# How To get Address Public Key from Account XPUB?

Tags: address, nodes, address-generation, xpub

I am little bit confused or not able to get the right Address Node Public key from Account XPUB.

What I have done :

1. Get the Account XPUB [78Bytes]
2. SHA-256
3. SHA-256 Again
4. Created Extended XPUB (XPUB + 4 Start Byte of Step 3)
5. Base 58 ENC
6. hdnode_deserialize()
7. Account Node  Change Node
8. Change Node  Address Node.

But am not able to get the right Public Address.

Please let me know if I have done something wrong.

Comment: What you want to achieve (derivation protocol) is precisely described and detailed in BIP32 https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#public-parent-key--public-child-key ...

Comment: I just want to get the Address Node Public Address by Account XPUB ..

Comment: i am writing my own application and somehow not able to get the right result and seek someone help

Answer (score 1):

To go from account xpub to address, you must first derive an xpub at the External index (0) or Internal index (1), then derive another xpub from the External/Internal xpub. Take the public key from the resulting xpub and this is the public key used for the address.

For a detailed explanation of extended public keys and how to derive child public keys, take a look at the [BIP32 documentation](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#public-parent-key--public-child-key). For a not-as-in-depth breakdown of deriving addresses from an extended public key (which is exactly what you're trying to do), I have written [this writeup](https://github.com/EAWF/BTC-Toolbox/blob/old-master/Address-Derivation.md).

Comment: can you explain it further more, see what steps i have followed to derive Address Node Public Key.
is there anything wrong in my implementation or pseudo code ?

Comment: @AmishSharma Your implementation/pseudocode is very wrong and not even close to what actually happens. Please read my answer, specifically the [second link.](https://github.com/EAWF/Bitcoin-Merchants-Toolbox/blob/master/Address-Derivation.md)

Comment: Sorry, but i i have done some mistake due to which i was not able to derive right address ..
My Pseudocode is perfectly fine .. By mistake i called hdnode_private_ckd() instead of hdnode_public_ckd()..

Comment: Thanks for your time and feedback..  appreciate it

Comment: @AmishSharma Please be careful with whatever you are doing. Your pseudocode does not do what you are asking in your question.

Comment: then how i got the desired result..
can you just tell me the your PseudoCode for Get Address Node Public key from Account Node XPUB. that would be appreciated

Comment: @AmishSharma See answer please...